# How to avoid duplication of code when you have more than 1 Shiny app in shinyDashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have 3 individual apps that I wanted to join in one single app. Although I know that there is a possibility to join them using [`navbarPage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680989/is-it-possible-to-add-a-sidebarpanel-and-a-mainpanel-in-each-tabpanel-using-navb/70682645#70682645)
, I decided to use `shinyDashboard`.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid repeating the code between the 3 apps everytime I use the same function. For example, if I use a slider in the first app and another one in the second app, I have to distinguish them writing a different `inputId`. Same happens when I want to put `dataTableOutput` in more than 1 app.

I have read about the `shinyModules` but I am having problems changing my code. So, for that reason I am trying to find another way.

Here you have a reproducible example:

- 3 apps where:

  - App 1 and App 2 have a `numericInput`, `sliderInput`, `checkboxInput` and `plotOutput` in common.
  - App 2 and App 3 have `radioButtons` and `DataTableOutput` in common.

I would like to avoid writing "THING_1", "SAME_THING_2", but I don't know if it is possible.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("App1", tabName = "App1", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("App2", tabName = "App2", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("App3", tabName = "App3", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabItems(
        
        tabItem(tabName = "App1",
                sidebarPanel(
                  numericInput("num",
                               "Select a number",
                               min = 1,
                               value = 10),
                
                  sliderInput("slider1",
                              "Number of bins:",
                              min = 1,
                              max = 50,
                              value = 30),
                  checkboxInput("remove", "Remove...", value = FALSE),
                  
                
                  
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  verbatimTextOutput("value"),
                  plotOutput("plot1"),
                  
                )
                
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "App2",
                sidebarPanel(
                  numericInput("num2",
                               "Select a number",
                               min = 1,
                               value = 10),
                  
                  sliderInput("slider2",
                              "Number of bins:",
                              min = 1,
                              max = 50,
                              value = 30),
                  
                  checkboxInput("remove2", "Remove...", value = FALSE),
                  checkboxInput("select", "I want to select....", value = FALSE),
                  radioButtons(inputId = "buttons", label="Decide...", c("Option1" = "Option 1",
                                                                         "Option2" = "Option 2"))

                ),
                mainPanel(
                  verbatimTextOutput("value2"),
                  plotOutput("plot2"),
                  dataTableOutput("table1")
                )
                
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "App3",
                sidebarPanel(
                  textInput("mytext", "Write text"),
                  radioButtons(inputId = "buttons", label="Decide...", c("Option1" = "Option 1",
                                                                         "Option2" = "Option 2"))

                ),
                mainPanel(
                  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
                  dataTableOutput("table2")
                )
                
                
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$value <- renderText({ input$num })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$slider1 + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- mtcars$mpg
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$slider2 + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
  
  output$text <-  renderText({ input$mytext })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    head(iris,15)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    head(mtcars,15)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does anyone know if there is way to avoid repeating the code all the time when I want to have the same thing for more than 1 app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Modularizing it and create a package, also have a look at the `golem` package https://engineering-shiny.org/golem.html

Comment: I find `golem` can be a little overengineered so you might struggle with it if you're already having issues with modules. I would say the best thing to do is put this project aside briefly and try to just follow along and reproduce the shiny modules tutorial until you get comfortable with the structure. Then try adding a new module as a test and once you feel good go back to the drawing board with this project.

Comment: Might also be worth starting from scratch as opposed to trying to convert the existing code.